# catch NAs using linear model with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

here's an exmaple data frame

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
   v2=factor(c("a","c","c","a","b","d")),
   v3=c(1,NA,NA,6,7,9),
   v4=c(5:10))
```

Note that `v3` contains NAs, so when I try to fit a linear model for each `id`, I get an error:

```
slope <- df %>% filter(v2=="c") %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  do(fit = lm(v3 ~ v4, .)) %>%
  summarise(slope = coef(fit)[2])

Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...)   : 
  0 (non-NA) cases
```

How can I catch this error and replace it with a default value if only NAs exist.

Note that it could also happen that `v4` has NAs, and if v3=c(1,NA) and
v4=c(NA,2) it could not build a linear model as well.

For example, if `df` does not contain any "c" then I can do this easily with

```
if(nrow(slope) == 0) slope <- 0
```

because then slope is an empty data frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use an `if/else` condition within `do` to check the `NA` elements.  If `all` the elements are `NA` in either 'v3' or (`|`) 'v4', it should return the slope as NA or `else` do the `lm` and get the slope value.

```
df %>% 
  filter(v2=='c') %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  do({if(all(is.na(.$v3))|all(is.na(.$v4))) 
              data.frame(slope=NA) 
             else data.frame(slope=coef(lm(v3~v4, .))[2])}) %>%
  slice(1L) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-id)
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2, 3, 3, 3,3, 3, 4, 4),
 v2=factor(c("a","c","c","a","b","d", "c", "c", "a", "c", "c", "c", "c")),
 v3=c(1,NA,NA,6,7,9, NA, 1, NA, 5,8, NA, 5 ),
 v4=c(5:17))
```

Comment: your solution still contains the id column, the original summarise solution omits it (which is what I want).

Comment: @spore234 You can `ungroup` and `select` to remove that column.

Comment: @spore234 I am not sure your method `summarise` would work with cases that have not all NAs as the 'fit' column from `do` is a `list`.  For example, using my example `df %>% filter(id %in% 3:4 & v2=='c') %>% do(fit= lm(v3~v4, .)) %>% summarise(slope=coef(fit)[2])
#Error: expecting result of length one, got : 0`

Answer (score 1):

If you are literally asking "how can I *catch* this error", you could *try* `tryCatch`.

This may be more useful depending on the situation, it would ignore only errors with the `"0 (non-NA) cases"` message, and you wouldn't have to do messy data checking.

You can also use `failwith` in the `plyr` package, though I believe that catches all error messages. However it is simpler to use.

```
all_na_msg <- "0 (non-NA) cases";
trymodel <- function(df, default = NA) {
  tryCatch(lm(v3 ~ v4, df),
           error = if (e$message == all_na_msg)
                     default
                   else
                     stop(e));
}

slope <- df %>% filter(v2=="c") %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  do(fit = trymodel(df)) %>%
  summarise(slope = coef(fit)[2])
```