# Tracking which group fails in a dplyr chain

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I find out which group failed when using `group_by` in a `dplyr` type chain. Take for example:

```
library(dplyr)

data(iris)

iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  do(mod=lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data = .)) %>%
  mutate(Slope = summary(mod)$coeff[2])
```

Works fine. Now if I add some problem data to `iris`:

```
iris$Petal.Width[iris$Species=="versicolor"]= NA
```

Such that it fails when trying to run a linear model:

```
iris_sub <- iris[iris$Species=="versicolor",]
lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data = iris_sub)
```

But if I was approaching this blind with a massive dataset if I ran this:

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  do(mod=lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data = .)) %>%
  mutate(Slope = summary(mod)$coeff[2])
```

This error message wouldn't help me find at which level the model failed:

> Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...)
>   :    0 (non-NA) cases

I could use a loop like below. This at least lets me know which level of `Species` the function fails on. However, I'd much prefer to use a dplyr setup:

```
lmdf <- c()
for (i in unique(iris$Species)) {
  cat(i, "\n")
  u <- iris %>%
    filter(Species==i) %>%
    do(mod=lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data = .))
  lmdf = rbind(lmdf, u)
}
```

Any suggestions regarding a better way to achieve this? To summarise, I am trying to use a `dplyr` type framework to determine at which group level, a function fails.

The `tryCatch` solution referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32357838/5596534) no longer seems to work. I get this error:

> Error in tryCatch(lm(v3 ~ v4, df), error = if (e$message ==
>   all_na_msg) default else stop(e)) :    object 'e' not found

Comment: Very close. Possible duplicate of [catch NAs using linear model with dplyr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32355773/catch-nas-using-linear-model-with-dplyr)

Comment: I feel maybe I have misrepresented the question a little. lm() could be any function at all that fails. What I am trying to do is figure at which group (or group combination) the function being called by do() fails.

Comment: @Axeman - I am intrigued by the purrr example. However I uncertain how to deal with list generated by `safe_lm. For example::  `safe_lm <- purrr::safely(lm)` then `safe_lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data = iris_sub)` outputs a list. How do I incorporate this into my chain `iris %>    group_by(Species) %>%    do(safe_lm(.))`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A full example of using `purrr::safely`:

#### Prep

```
library(tidyverse)
data(iris)
iris$Petal.Width[iris$Species == "versicolor"] <-  NA
```

#### Safely run the models

If you're uninterested in the actual error (i.e. that the cause was `0 (non-NA) cases`), you can do:

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  do(mod = safely(lm)(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data = .)$result) %>% 
  mutate(Slope = ifelse(!is.null(mod), summary(mod)$coeff[2], NA))
```

And we're done!

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 3 × 3
     Species      mod     Slope
      <fctr>   <list>     <dbl>
1     setosa <S3: lm> 0.5464903
2 versicolor   <NULL>        NA
3  virginica <S3: lm> 0.6472593
```

We can clearly see which group failed (because it has `NULL` instead of a model, and it's `Slope` is unknown). Moreover, we still obtained the correct models and slopes for the other groups, so we haven't wasted computation time (this can be quite nice when running complex models on larger datasets).

#### Keeping track of both the models *and* the errors

```
step1 <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  do(res = safely(lm)(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data = .)) %>%
  mutate(err = map(list(res), 'error'),
         mod = map(list(res), 'result'))
```

Unfortunately, we have to use extra `list` calls there, not entirely sure why. Alternatively, you can `ungroup` first.

To see which (if any) groups have error-ed, we can use:

```
filter(step1, !is.null(err))
```

To rescue the result of the non-errored groups simply `filter` first:

```
step1 %>% 
  filter(is.null(err)) %>% 
  mutate(Slope = summary(mod)$coeff[2])
```

You could also look into the `broom` package if want to obtain the coefficients of models within tidy chains.

Comment: This is it! Quick follow up: if I had a tibble like this:  `6 <list [2]> <NULL> <data.frame [1 × 4]>` - how would I extract the dataframe? I see how you did it with the model result. But how do I extract a dataframe?

Comment: Use `unnest`, I would guess, but you may have to `filter` out the `NULL` rows first.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not wedded to `dplyr`, you could use a split-apply approach and `try` in base R. Here's one way to do that:

```
# use split to make a list of data sets by group (here, species)
iris.split <- split(iris, iris$Species)

# iterate your modeling function over that list, using 'try' to let the
# process keep running when an error is thrown and logging an object of
#class "try-error" in that slot on the resulting list
iris.mods <- lapply(iris.split, function(i) try(lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data = i)))

# get a vector of slopes from those models with NA where any errors killed
# the modeling process
slopes <- sapply(iris.mods, function(x) ifelse(is(x, "try-error"), NA, x$coefficients[2]))
```

Result:

```
> slopes
    setosa versicolor  virginica 
 0.5464903         NA  0.6472593
```

Comment: This is really an awesome answer. Unfortunately I am wedded to dplyr in this case.